# How would I do tasks after a render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm about to build a Notification system for my Android app that has a Rails backend. Whenever someone comments on a post, I want to notify everyone involved.

Sure, I could do something like:

```
def create
  #Process commenting on the post
  #Process sending notification to all involved

  render :ok
end
```

That being said, I don't want the sending of notifications to slow down the request. Ultimately, it is does not decide the fate of whether or not the post was created.

I think the best solution might be to add the task to a background worker, which has a queue of notifications being sent out. Is there a better/different solution to be used for things like this? How would this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using `ActiveJob`, described in [this Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). The concept of what you're trying to do and the way `ActionMailer` works is very similar; it's just that you're sending notifications instead of emails. You'd enqueue a notify job using a callback the same way you might send an email when a new user signs up, as described in section 2.1.4 of [the ActionMailer Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- add a callback `after_commit :notify_others, on: :create` in the comment model
- the `notify_others` method should invoke a job (`NewCommentNotifierJob`) with the comment just created
- in the perform method of the `NewCommentNotifierJob`, using the comment, determine all the involved parties that should receive email notifications and schedule an email delivery

So for each new comment you will schedule 1 job that will schedule N jobs to send the email notifications.